# Can Xcode build native Intel binaries on a M1 Mac from command line tools?

Tags: xcode, makefile, arch, xcode-command-line-tools

This is an additional question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834349/can-xcode-build-native-intel-binaries-on-a-m1-mac). I also want to compile a universal binary (or two separate ones for x86_64 and arm64). However, I am not using Xcode, but the Xcode command line tools. So far, I have only found the manual to do so for Xcode itself. How can I do this, if I just use `make` in command line?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe this helps somebody: I just tried to use `make` after switching to the Rosetta Terminal via `arch -x86_64 zsh`. `lipo -archs` no displays `x86_64`, so it looks fine.